# Custom EL function inside composite component not working

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, taglib, composite-component

Trying a different approach to solve the problem I mentioned [here](http://goo.gl/EF9X8), I created a facelets taglib to use some formatting functions.

It works fine for normal pages, but for composite components the function is not executed and no error is thrown.

Taglib file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://www.spdata.com.br/jsf</namespace>

   <composite-library-name>spd</composite-library-name>

    <function>
        <function-name>leftJustifyWithZeros</function-name>
        <function-class>
            br.com.spdata.util.Formatter
        </function-class>
        <function-signature>
            String leftJustifyWithZeros(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)
        </function-signature>
    </function>

    <function>
        <function-name>replaceNewLineWithBrTag</function-name>
        <function-class>
            br.com.spdata.util.Formatter
        </function-class>
        <function-signature>
            String replaceNewLineWithBrTag(java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function>    
</facelet-taglib>
```

Composite component:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"    
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:spd="http://www.spdata.com.br/jsf"
>

   <cc:interface>
      <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
   </cc:interface>

   <cc:implementation>
      <h:outputText 
         id="#{cc.attrs.id == null ? 'visualizar' : cc.attrs.id}"
         value="Visualizar"
         rendered="#{cc.attrs.value != null and not empty cc.attrs.value}"
         />   
      <p:tooltip 
         value="#{spd:replaceNewLineWithBrTag(cc.attrs.value)}" 
         for="#{cc.attrs.id == null ? 'visualizar' : cc.attrs.id}" 
         />   
   </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Phillip

Comment: The symptoms are much similar to a known Mojarra 2.1.7/2.1.8 specific bug related to wrong XML namespace interpretation inside composite components. What JSF impl/version are you using? What if you move the `xmlns:spd` namespace declaration from `<html>` into `<cc:implementation>`?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.10. Moving the declaration to cc:implementation didn't solved.